# Unity Networking Lobby : Set player name

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I work on my Networking Lobby of my 2D Game and I have a little issue with the name of my player :

I downloaded [this example](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41836) to help me

But as you can see, the name of the player can be changed when you have join the game and you entered in the lobby.

But in my project, I want to write my name, click on Valid, and connect to the lobby. Like that :

[image]

My problem is I don't know how can I use my InputField text as name for my player in my Lobby.

I try to save the name in a static Class with static property, but every players have the same name.

This is my code :

```
//Attached to my Name Panel
public class LobbyName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LobbyManager LobbyManager;
    public Text TxtName;

    public void OnClickValidName()
    {
        Constants.PlayerName = TxtName.text;

        LobbyManager.ChangeTo(LobbyManager.MenuLobby);
    }
}

//Attached to my canvas
public class LobbyManager : NetworkLobbyManager
{
    public Button BackButton;

    private RectTransform _currentPanel;
    public RectTransform ListLobby;
    public RectTransform MenuLobby;
    public RectTransform NameLobby;

    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    private void Start()
    {
        _currentPanel = NameLobby; 

        NameLobby.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ChangeTo(RectTransform newPanel)
    {
        if (_currentPanel != null)
            _currentPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        if (newPanel != null)
            newPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        _currentPanel = newPanel;
    }
}

//Attached to my Player Item
public class LobbyPlayer : NetworkLobbyPlayer
{
    public Text TxtPlayerName;

    public string PlayerName = "";

    public override void OnClientEnterLobby()
    {
        base.OnClientEnterLobby();

        TxtPlayerName.text = Constants.PlayerName;

        LobbyPlayerList.Instance.AddPlayer(this);
    }
}

//Attached to my Menu lobby panel
public class LobbyMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LobbyManager LobbyManager; 

    public void OnClickConnect()
    {
        LobbyManager.StartClient();

        LobbyManager.ChangeTo(LobbyManager.ListLobby); 
    }
}
```

I know my static class not working because I have just ONE instance.

(In the asset example, the playerName can be changed in the lobby panel, but I don't want the same configuration)

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NetworkIdentity -localPlayerAuthority.

Comment: Hey Sajmoon, thanks for your reply. I solved my answer with PlayerPrefs. I know it isn't a good solution, but my player have already the same name, same if he leave. Can you share me an example with name property plz?